# How to handle DML exceptions in apex class WITH USER_MODE?

Tags: apex, exception, dml, dmlexception

> I'm trying to do a DML with user mode in apiVersion 58.0.

I got "**DML Exception**" while inserting records without field permission and I got "**SecurityException**" while inserting records without object permission. Is there any way to handle both under single exception or I need to handle these two as two different exception?

This is my code,

```
try {
      Contact con = new Contact();
      con.FirstName = 'Test';
      con.LastName = 'Contact';
      con.Email__c = 'abc@xyz.com';
      insert as user con;
    } catch (DMLException e) {
        String error = String.join(new List<String>(e.getDmlFieldNames(0)),', ')+' does not have access permission';
        throw new CustomException(error);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: I'd use two catch blocks but if handling is identical, then call a common method

Comment: Thanks @cropredy